# rospy publishers using tons of CPU

Tags: ros, rospy, ros-kinetic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node with a number of subscribers and publishers in it. Most of them have no problem, but 2 in particular running at 100hz are taking up about 15% of an i7 CPU set with a queue_size of 10.

When the application runs with just the publish line commented out, it drops 15%. I've never seen anything like this in C++ and wasn't sure if there was some quirk in python needed to address high rate topics.

Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289897/rospy-publishers-using-tons-of-cpu/) by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8272 on 2018-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-27**:
It's hard to comment on this without seeing your code, but I've mostly used `rospy` and haven't run into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found when I changed the 100hz topics to having a queue_size of None, the CPU immediately dropped to the 15% less, if all other topics are also None, no real difference, appears to only be an issue for the high rate ones.

I need to look into the ramifications of it but seems like a plausible fix.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0